# iPad: Better way than invisible button on background to let users exit entries?

Tags: iphone, ipad

On iPad/iPhone, Do you still need to make an invisible button on background to let users exit entries?  Is there a better way to dismiss the keyboard when users click outside of an entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in the ViewController to call `resignFirstResponder` on the active control from there.

// edit:

My Views contain several UITextFields; I want the keyboard to disappear when the user touches anywhere besides a TextField or the keyboard, so my ViewController has this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [currentTextfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This causes the keyboard to disappear. (I keep track of the current textfield elsewhere.)

Comment: Can you please elaborate with more sample code?  I'm not sure what you are suggesting?

Comment: Wow, thank you!  This works great!  I don't even track the currentTextField, I just resignFirstResponder on every single text input on the screen which seems to have no bad side-effects.